# ebay API - get UPC's from list of auctions

Tags: c#, .net, ebay-api

there are certain items on ebay that have UPC in their description. for example CDs and other media have a field in the actual description of the item called UPC and books have ISBN right in the description. is it possible to programmatically capture this information? most preferably solution would be in .NET.

Comment: this is a very interesting question

Comment: does anyone have any feedback or advice?

Comment: why does the question kept asking as if it where in a loop:
"there are certain items on ebay that have UPC in their description...."

Answer (score 2):

Those details should be available in the listing's attributes which is `ItemType.AttributeArray`

Comment: please give me an example of URL using ProductSearch.ExternalProductID

Comment: was wondering if you can help out wtih this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6929259/ebay-api-returning-auctions-ending-later-than-10-days

Answer (score 2):

well based on what it is stated on their API reference you probably could use http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/GetProducts.html GetProducts call.

More particularly the Trading API in an area that refers to a conditional request with name:
ProductSearch.ExternalProductID

"A query that only retrieves items that were listed with stock products that have ISBN or UPC values (such as books, DVDs, CDs, and video game products). Use this query to retrieve basic details about one catalog product (or a very limited number of products). The results can optionally include items, reviews, and/or buying guides that match that product. (Specifically, the items returned are items that sellers listed with the specified product's stock information.)"

for xml samples of this call refer to http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/WebHelp/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm?context=eBay_XML_API&topic=GetProductsSamples

regarding .net accelerator ebay offers one at http://developer.ebay.com/developercenter/windows/sdk/ 
download and test calls.

one more thing, I usually test xml calls using ALTOVA suite(xml). I suggest you to do the same.
brgds.

Comment: this is a really good answer thanks so much. can you please show me how i would use the externalproductID what woould the URL look lke?

Comment: the best way to create your api call to test is to register here : http://www.sandbox.ebay.com/ and follow steps. the API test tool will give you the chance to create an xml request receiving an response with the ack ok.

Comment: thank you i am able to test it but i do not understand how to build the url?????????

Comment: do you pass the XML to ebay and it gives you the result?

Comment: you can use different formats & protocols as stated on http://developer.ebay.com/products/shopping/ , Protocols: HTTP GET (REST) and POST . For a typical url request checkout this page: http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/shopping/docs/Concepts/ShoppingAPI_FormatOverview.html

Comment: was wondering if you can help out wtih this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6929259/ebay-api-returning-auctions-ending-later-than-10-days

Comment: I dont know exactly about the 10 day limits but ebay managed historical listings through a parent company called dataunison.com . if you want to retrieve historical info, average prices and more you will need to get in contact with them. dataunison charges fees per api call. check developer.ebay.com -> programs -> market data. hope it helps

Comment: i appreeciate your response. it's not that i want historical listings i just want listings that end in 20 days or 21 days. so far i have not able to find anything that will allow me more than 10 days